# position edit and label for input field

Tags: html, css

I want to place the edit and my input label like this:

[image]

So I tried this with no like:

```css
 input {
  display: inline-block;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ededed;
  color: #743db0;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

input:focus {
  color: #8e5bc5;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #e7572c;
}

.input-field {

}

.input-field  label {
  float: left;
  /*width: 10em;*/
  /*margin-right: 1em;*/
}

 .data {
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
}

 .data .edit {
  font-family: "IRANSansWeb_Light";
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <div class="name">
    <p>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="fname">
          <span>User Name</span>
          <span>:</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="user_1252442">
        <a class="edit">Edit</a>
      </div>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can we **properly** fix this?

Answer (score 1):

CSS Update:

```
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper .edit {
  font-family: "IRANSansWeb_Light";
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  
}
```

HTML Update:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="user_1252442">
   <a class="edit">Edit</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your input margin so edit sits below it and floated the label to the right and added a `display: inline-block` to your input-field.

```css
input {
    display: inline-block;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    width: 300px;
    background: #ededed;
    color: #743db0;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  }
  
  input:focus {
    color: #8e5bc5;
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #e7572c;
  }

  .input-field {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19em;
  }
  
  label {
    float: right;
  }
  a {
      display: block;
  }
   .data {
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  }
  
   .data .edit {
    font-family: "IRANSansWeb_Light";
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  
  }
```

```html
    <div class="data">
        <div class="name">
          <p>
      
            <div class="input-field">
              <label for="fname">
                <span>User Name</span>
                <span>:</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="user_1252442">
              <a class="edit">Edit</a>
            </div>
      
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add flex to get the best result.

```css
input {
    display: inline-block;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    width: 300px;
    background: #ededed;
    color: #743db0;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    /* margin: 0 25px 0 25px; */
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  }
  
  input:focus {
    color: #8e5bc5;
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #e7572c;
  }
  
  .input-field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column ;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 320px;
  }
  
  .input-field  label {
    float: left;
    /*width: 10em;*/
    /*margin-right: 1em;*/
  }
  
   .data {
    margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
  }
  
   .data .edit {
    font-family: "IRANSansWeb_Light";
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  
  }
  .uname{
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    
            <div class="input-field">
              <div for="fname" class="uname">
                : User Name
              </div>
              <div><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="user_1252442"/></div>
              <div><a class="edit">Edit</a></div>
            </div>
    

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>  -->
</body>
</html>
```

I commented out some of your code. Please check and let me know if anymore help requires.